# Move contents of hidden child div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to move the contents of the hidden child div with class details to the div with id section1target but it says details is not defined.

I also tried

---

```
$( '.profile' ).click(function() {
    $('#section1target').html($(this + '.details').html());

    //also tried..
    $('#section1target').html($(this).next('.details').html());
});

<div class="container marginT30">
    <ul class="thumbnails row-fluid" id="section1">
        <li class="span3 offset3 profile">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <img src="img.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <h3></h3>
                    <h4 class="marginT10">Title</h4>
                    <div class="row-fluid details hidden-details">
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect
                        </p>
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ad
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="span3 profile">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <img src="img.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <h3></h3>
                    <h4 class="marginT10">Title</h4>
                    <div class="row-fluid details">
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor
                        </p>
                        <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="section1target"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#section1target').html($(this).find(".details").html());
```

`.next()` only works if the element is the immediately next sibling, not a descendant. `$(this)+".details"` doesn't make sense at all, since `$(this)` is a jQuery object, not a string.

Comment: it still tells me .details is not defined

Comment: It sounds to me like you have a missing quote in your code. jQuery doesn't report any error when it can't find a selector.

Comment: I didn't get any error in your fiddle. It didn't do anything because there's no `section1target` DIV, I fixed that in http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/uSmaU/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `this` as your selector context, since the element that you are looking for is a descendant of it.

```
$('#section1target').html($('.details',this).html());
```